# How to check if all items in a SemanticsNodeInteractionCollection exist in Jetpack Compose unit testing?

Tags: android, unit-testing, automated-tests, android-jetpack-compose

Consider the following assertions:

```
class BasicTest {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Test
    fun myTest(): Unit = with(composeTestRule) {
        setContent { App() }
 
        // To check if a single node has a click action:
        onNodeWithText("foo").assertHasClickAction() // OK
        // To check if multiple nodes have a click action:
        onAllNodesWithText("foo").assertAll(hasClickAction()) // OK
        
        // To check if a single node exists:
        onNodeWithText("foo").assertExists() // OK
        // To check if a multiple nodes exists, there is no fitting method??
        onAllNodesWithText("foo").assertAll(exists()) // No exists() or similar method for assertExists()
    }
}
```

With the result of `onAllNodesWithText("foo")`, how would I check all the fitting nodes exist?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with this extension

```
    private fun SemanticsNodeInteractionCollection.assertAreDisplayed(): SemanticsNodeInteractionCollection {
        fetchSemanticsNodes().forEachIndexed { index, _ ->
            get(index).assertIsDisplayed()
        }
        return this
    }
```

And use it like this

```
composeTestRule
    .onAllNodesWithText("foo")
    .assertAreDisplayed()
```